# JavaScript and PHP values toggle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

I have index.php page and I have this there:

```
$pv->showHidden = isset($_POST['showHidden']) ? intval($_POST['showHidden']) : 0;
$pv->sendHidden = isset($_POST['showHidden']) ? 0 : 1;
```

and then I have this:

```
<input type="image" id="btnShowHidden" src="images/hide.gif" onclick="showHiddenRecords(<?php print $pv->sendHidden; ?>);" />
```

I have JavaScript that has this function:

```
function showHiddenRecords(x){
 alert(x);
 var n = new Object();
 var showHidden;
 if(x=1){Y=0;} else {Y=1;}
 n.showHidden = Y;
 Ajax.Post("index.php", n, pg.test(x));
      
}
```

What I am trying to do is to toggle the value of `$pv->showHidden`, so if it is 1 (already selected)   then it will become 0 and vice versa, but the logic isn't working.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have `if(x=1)` in your function. should be `if(x==1)` to compare. or else you are just setting x to 1.